# Only one selected item allowed in ListView

Tags: compact-framework

I need only one ListView item selectable. I can not find poperty/method to disable multiple selection in .NET Compact Framework 3.5. And I can not find ListView2 in OpenNetCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [ListBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2swkx91x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It can be made to look and function like the [ListView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwb14tw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

[image: screenshot]

If you want (or need) to stick with the ListView Control, you could always select the first item in the [SelectionIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event and discard the rest.

```
void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++) {
    ListViewItem item = ListView1.SelectedItems[i];
    if (i == 0) {
      Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    } else {
      item.Selected = false;
    }
  }
}
```